# Preg_replace all patterns in a string

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a str like :

```
'Test code {B}{X} we are implementing prototype {T} ,
 using combinations of {U}{A} and {L/W}{F/K}.
```

I need to replace each occurance of {*} with it's corresponding code, so my resulting string would be:

```
   'Test code <img src="../B.jpg"><img src="../X.jpg"> 
    we are implementing prototype <img src="../T.jpg"> 
    ,using combinations of <img src="../U.jpg">
    <img src="../A.jpg"> and <img src="../LW.jpg">
    <img src="../FK.jpg">.
```

I don't wish to use `str_replace` and type out all the combinations because there is literally thousands of them.
`$combinations = array("{B}", "{X}", "{W}{X},"{X/W}","{A/L}"..");` etc

So i'm using preg_match_all to find all occurrences with the string.

```
function findMatches($start, $end, $str){
    $matches = array();
    $regex = "/$start([\/a-zA-Z0-9_]*)$end/";
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Which returns to me,

```
Array ( [0] => B [1] => X [2] => T [3] => U [4] => A [5] => L/W [6] => F/K )
```

The problem is I don't need the '/' between letters, which I suppose I could str_replace later.

**My question is how can I preg_replace using the array of matches and return the fully modified string back instead of the array?**

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job. What you want is `preg_replace_callback`. Also, it's totally unclear what exactly you are doing with `findMatches`.

Comment: No idea about this language. but try `/\{(.)\}/` and replace it with $1 that is matched group at index 1 within `()`. It works I have tested at [here](https://www.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html). For e.g `preg_replace('/\\{(.)\\}/', '$1', input_string)` and there are 5 matches.

Comment: Try `/\{([^}].*?)\}/` as well that matches more than one letters inside {}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to achieve this. You can then use the `str_replace()` method to replace the forward slash `/` in your match that the callback function returns.

```
$text = <<<DATA
Test code {B}{X} we are implementing prototype {T} ,
 using combinations of {U}{A} and {L/W}{F/K}. 
DATA;

$text = preg_replace_callback('~{([^}]*)}~', 
      function($m) {
         return '<img src="../' . str_replace('/', '', $m[1]) . '.jpg">';
      }, $text);

echo $text;
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/165317)

Comment: ah this works great thanks didn't know about preg_replace_callback

Answer (score 1):

This will get you halfway there, but you still need one more replace to remove the `/`

```
<?php
$input='Test code {B}{X} we are implementing prototype {T} ,
 using combinations of {U}{A} and {L/W}{F/K}.';

$output = preg_replace("/{([^}]*)}/", '<img src="../' . '\\1' . '.jpg">', $input);
echo $output."\n";
?>
```

Output:

```
Test code <img src="../B.jpg"><img src="../X.jpg"> we are implementing prototype <img src="../T.jpg"> ,
 using combinations of <img src="../U.jpg"><img src="../A.jpg"> and <img src="../L/W.jpg"><img src="../F/K.jpg">.
```

Comment: how can i replace the '/' inside of {L/W}{F/K} to be just LW.jpg or FK.jpg?